# How does select SUBSTRING('uppercase ', LEN('uppercase')-2, 3) result in "ase"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see below query:

```
select SUBSTRING('uppercase ', LEN('uppercase')-2, 3)
```

Can someone explain how it is working and giving output as **ase**

Please help.

Comment: If you've read the documentation and don't understand the output, please explain *what you expected* vs what it's producing, with as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 4):

**SUBSTRING** function extracts characters from a string. In additon,**LEN** function provide the length of string. the **LEN('uppercase')** would be 9.

```
SUBSTRING(string, start, length)
```

your query is like

```
select SUBSTRING('uppercase ', LEN('uppercase')-2, 3)---equivalent

select SUBSTRING('uppercase ', 9-2, 3) --equivalent
select SUBSTRING('uppercase ', 7, 3)
```

hence it provide **ase**

Comment: So will it work in all cases if I want the last three characters of any string (of any length) as output?

Comment: yes if you must consider the syntax select SUBSTRING(string1, LEN(string1)-2, 3)

Comment: equivalent to SELECT RIGHT(string1, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
select SUBSTRING('uppercase ', LENGTH('uppercase')-2, 3)  // Mysql hasn't len function 

LENGTH('uppercase') // return 9, the length of string.
SUBSTRING('uppercase ', 9-2, 3) // return a substring from the index of 7 and three characters, that is ase
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the documentation of [substring function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
>
> expression
> Is a character, binary, text, ntext, or image expression.
>
> start
> Is an integer or bigint expression that specifies where the
> returned characters start. (The numbering is 1 based, meaning that the
> first character in the expression is 1). If start is less than 1, the
> returned expression will begin at the first character that is
> specified in expression. In this case, the number of characters that
> are returned is the largest value of either the sum of start + length-
> 1 or 0. If start is greater than the number of characters in the value
> expression, a zero-length expression is returned.
>
> length
> Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how
> many characters of the expression will be returned. If length is
> negative, an error is generated and the statement is terminated. If
> the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters
> in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is
> returned.

In your case,

```sql
SUBSTRING('uppercase ', LEN('uppercase')-2, 3)
SUBSTRING('uppercase ', 9-2, 3)
SUBSTRING('uppercase ', 7, 3)
```

```
u p p e r c a s e
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
            <====> (From 7 pick 3 characters)
```

> a s e